# Python: multiline regular expression problem

Tags: python, regex

I have a very long string, the first lines of which are:

```
text = """




[text begins here] ... """
```

I want to remove all the `\n` characters at the beginning of it, so that I get only something like:

```
text = """[text begins here] ... """
```

I'm trying the following:

```
pattern = r"^\n*"
search = re.compile(pattern, re.S)
out = re.sub(pattern, "", text)
```

But it doesn't catch or replace anything.

How can I fix this?

(Note: I need to use RegEx for this, not string slicing or other methods.)

Comment: Have you tried using `strip()`?

Comment: Your three lines worked perfectly for me. Maybe you have a leading space or something in your `text` value. (And also, having to use a regex is odd because `lstrip` is best for this kind of thing; however, I won't judge your reasons. Cheers.)

Comment: @anubhava I've never of heard of `search` before, what's it's used for?

Comment: `search` is function in python to preform regex based search

Comment: @FuzzySquid I need a regex solution.

Comment: @anubhava But it's in the `re` module, so `re.search != search` when you `import re`.

Comment: Your code works for me, you might be seeing CRLF somehow if you're on Windows.  I'd try changing your regexp to `^[\r\n]*`, or just using `strip()` as others suggest.

Comment: @anubhava You're probably right. I'll change the variable name.

Comment: @AnonCoward No, I'm on Linux...

Comment: str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$|\s+(?=\s)/g, "");

Comment: `re.sub(r"\n", '', text)`?

Comment: @yatu That will remove all line breaks, not only the first ones, of my text.

Comment: @FuzzySquid Is that Python?

Answer (score 2):

You can perform a left-strip on your text using `str.lstrip`:

```
out = text.lstrip()
```

Comment: Thanks. But I need a regex solution.

Comment: @NVaughan Your regex works for me, it's probably a platform-specific problem as @AnonCoward mentioned in the comments, which you can avoid by using `str.lsplit`.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have more than just linefeed characters (`\n`) in your string (like carriage return (`\r`)). You should just use lstrip like the others have said, but the following regex should work:

```
re.sub(r'^[\r\n]*', '', text)
```

Comment: why not use `\s` to capture all white space?

Comment: @Dion the question was how to remove the leading newlines, so I thought other white space should be left untouched. Otherwise r'^\s*' would indeed be better.